# Morris graph not displaying

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, morris.js

I need to do a graph for each of the bootstrap tabs created, I have four tabs from four columns in my database and each tab should show the graph for that particular column. Here is the code to retrieve and echo the tabs required

```
 <?php 

    require_once("../include/membersite_config.php");
    $username = $_SESSION['username_of_user'];

    $config = parse_ini_file('../private/config.ini');     
    $connect = mysqli_connect($config['servername'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);

    $tab_query = "SELECT * FROM ".$config['tablenamenode']." WHERE username = '".$username."' ORDER BY id ASC";
    $tab_result = mysqli_query($connect, $tab_query);
    $tab_menu = '';
    $tab_content = '';
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tab_result))
    {
        if($i == 0)
        {
            $tab_menu .= '
            <li class="active"><a href="#'.$row["gatewayno"].'" data-toggle="tab">'.$row["description"].'</a></li>
            ';

            $tab_content .= '
            <div id="'.$row["gatewayno"].'" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="'.$row['gatewayno'].'" style="height:200px"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            ';

            $gatewayno[] = $row["gatewayno"];

        }
        else
        {
            $tab_menu .= '
            <li><a href="#'.$row['gatewayno'].'" data-toggle="tab">'.$row["description"].'</a></li>
            ';

            /*$tab_content .= '
            <div id="'.$row["gatewayno"].'" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div id="morris-area-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px; padding: 30px;" >
            </div>
            </div>
            ';*/


            $tab_content .= '<div class="tab-pane fade" id="'.$row['gatewayno'].'">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="'.$row['gatewayno'].'" style="height:200px"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            ';

            /*$tab_content .= '
            <div id="'.$row["gatewayno"].'" class="tab-pane fade">
            ';*/

            $gatewayno[] = $row["gatewayno"];

        }

        //$tab_content .= '</div>';
        $i++;
    }

?>
```

HTML Code to display the tabs and contents

```
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <!-- AREA CHART -->

          <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <!-- Tabs within a box -->
            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
              <!--<li class="active"><a href="#morris-area-chart" data-toggle="tab">Donut</a></li>-->
              <li class="pull-left header"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i> Temperature and Humidity</li>

              <?php
                echo $tab_menu;
              ?>

            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content no-padding">
              <!-- Morris chart - Sales --> 
              <!--<div class="chart tab-pane active" id="morris-area-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px; padding: 30px;" ></div> -->

              <?php
                echo $tab_content;
               ?>

            </div>

          </div>

            <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
          <!-- /.box -->  
        </div>

        <!-- /.col (RIGHT) -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->
```

PHP CODE and javascript to initialise the graph

```
<?php

$n = 0;

foreach($gatewayno as $key => $value)
{
    ?>
<script>

var <?php echo $value ?> = Morris.Area({
    // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
element: '<?php echo $value ?>',

behaveLikeLine: true,

    // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point
    // on the chart.

    // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
xkey: 'timestamp',

    // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
ykeys: ['humidity','temperature'],

    // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
    // chart.
labels: ['Humidity', 'Temperature'],

    //lineColors: ['#3da1231'],
xLabels: 'hour',

    // Disables line smoothing
smooth: true,
resize: true
});

</script>

<?php

    $n++;
}
?>

<?php

foreach($gatewayno as $key => $value)
{

?>
<script>

function update<?php echo $value ?>(){


 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "charts-ajax-testing.php", // This is the URL to the API
      data: {id: <?php echo $value ?>},

      success: function(html)                    
      {   
        <?php echo $value ?>.setData(html);
        alert("TEST"."<?php echo $value?>");
      }

    });
 }

setInterval(update<?php echo $value ?>,5000);

</script>

<?php 

}

?>
```

However, none of the graphs are showing up in the tab. Upon inspection, I found this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at d.<anonymous> (morris.min.js:6)
    at d.b.Grid.d._calc (morris.min.js:6)
    at d.b.Grid.d.redraw (morris.min.js:6)
    at d.b.Grid.d.resizeHandler (morris.min.js:6)
    at morris.min.js:6
```

when resizing the browser

Here is the code upon inspection

[image: Inspection of code]

Comment: This seems to be an error related the the morris.js library itself. Make sure you have the latest version of the library.

Comment: I have used the latest morris library from the website and now while inspecting I can this error message from the console

morris.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined
    at d.b.Line.c.onGridClick (morris.min.js:6)
    at morris.min.js:6
    at o (jquery.js:7309)
    at j (jquery.js:7426)
    at j (jquery.js:7427)
    at Function.st.param (jquery.js:7329)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.js:7815)
    at updatea111111 (charts-testing2.php:414)

Comment: You seem to be missing the "data" field, or did you intentionally leave that out in your example?

Comment: you should trim your question a bit, remove unwanted code which is distracting actual context.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `data` field in your `Morris.Area` call.

According to the [documentation](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) the "data" field is required, and you don't seem to have included it in your call.

> The data to plot. This is an array of objects, containing x and y
>   attributes as described by the *xkey* and *ykeys* options.

Comment: Hi, after adding the data field I am getting this error

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at o (jquery.js:7309)
    at j (jquery.js:7426)
    at j (jquery.js:7427)
    at j (jquery.js:7427)
    at j (jquery.js:7427)
    at j (jquery.js:7427)
    at Function.st.param (jquery.js:7329)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.js:7815)
    at updatea111114 (charts-testing2.php:510)